# Format problem when using awk in python script

Tags: python, awk

I am trying to write following command in python script:

```
cmd = '''awk '{printf "%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' %s.txt > %s.txt''' % (file_name_1, file_name_2)
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

But it failed to execute due to argument problem. First three `"%.6f"` is for awk output format, last two `"%s"` is for file name. I tried to add `"r"` after `"="` but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: why using `awk` to do the job when python can do the same?

Comment: the issue is with `\n`. Use a raw string for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `\n` character in the command isn't passed to `awk` as `\n` but as a linefeed in the command line.

You need to use raw prefix so `\n` is passed literally:

```
cmd = r'''awk '{printf "%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' %s.txt > %s.txt''' %  (file_name_1, file_name_2)
```

(and yes, thanks to reading [Glenn other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212243/6451573), I saw that I forgot about doubling the `%` char so really not very convenient solution unless you use `format` instead, the fix is only partial)

using `str.format` and double quotes (no need for triple single quotes here):

```
cmd = r"awk '{printf "%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' {}.txt > {}.txt".format(file_name_1, file_name_2)
```

Better yet, rewrite this in pure python using `open`, `str.split` on iterated lines and float conversion. Untested but should work great:

```
with open(file_name_1+".txt") as fr, open(file_name_2+".txt","w") as fw:
    for line in fr:
      toks = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
      fw.write("%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\n" % (toks[0]-10,toks[1],toks[2]))
```

- more portable (no need for `awk`, ex on Windows)
- if the filenames have spaces in them, it's not an issue
- avoids a system call

Comment: I am more familiar with this. I tried your solution but it does not work as I mentioned in question.

Comment: OK. Thanks for posting python solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the `%` in the format string to insert literal percent chars in the resulting string

```
cmd = r'''awk '{printf "%%.6f  %%.6f  %%.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' %s.txt > %s.txt''' % (file_name_1, file_name_2)
# ......................^^.....^^.....^^
```

As in:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file_name_1 = 'foo'
>>> file_name_2 = 'bar'
>>> cmd = '''awk '{printf "%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' %s.txt > %s.txt''' % (file_name_1, file_name_2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float argument required, not str
>>> cmd = r'''awk '{printf "%%.6f  %%.6f  %%.6f\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}' %s.txt > %s.txt''' % (file_name_1, file_name_2)
>>> cmd
'awk \'{printf "%.6f  %.6f  %.6f\\n",$1-10.0,$2,$3}\' foo.txt > bar.txt'
```

Comment: Hey everyone, vote for Jean-François Fabre's answer.

Comment: Thanks for this post!

Comment: @glennjackman thanks :) I voted for _your_ answer as well because it _shows_ what happens.